# how do i install pip in cygwin?

Tags: pip, cygwin-x

I want to install pip in cygwin (Windows 10). When I try that I get the comment that the destination file is missing. So how can I choose file? Is there any way to see the entire file system in cygwin? I have, or so I thought, already installed pip from cygwin installation package but when I try to run pip (or virtualenv) from cygwin I only get back command not found. So, if the question seems confused then it reflects my state of mind accurately.

Comment: Although he asks about viewing file system in cygwin, I believe he wants to install pip, so I answered that. As far as the file system in cygwin, it is 'hiding' in C:\cygwin64. For example the home directory \home\username is on the windows file system at c:\cygwin64\home\username

Comment: I suspect this question was closed in error. but in any case, open the cygwin installer again, and search for "pip" under install-able packages, you will find a package named something like `python38-pip`, installing this package gives you the command `pip3.8`,  now run: `pip3.8 install --upgrade pip` , once that finishes, the `pip` command is finally available, and it should be the latest released version of pip, mission complete :)

Answer (score 6):

In CYGWIN it is best to install packages via the CYGWIN installation program. Even for other installation packages like pip.

Run the CYGWIN installation program again. Select the pip package you want. Currently, python3-pip and python2-pip are available.

Running this installation again only updates your current CYGWIN installation and does not hurt anything you have installed already.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @SamMurphy pip3.8 install colorama